# How do I replace part of a string with a lua filter in Pandoc, to convert from .md to .pdf?

Tags: pdf, lua, markdown, pandoc

I am writing markdown files in Obsidian.md and trying to convert them via Pandoc and LaTeX to PDF. Text itself works fine doing this, howerver, in Obsidian I use ==equal signs== to highlight something, however this doesn't work in LaTeX.

So I'd like to create a filter that either removes the equal signs entirely, or replaces it with something LaTeX can render, e.g. `\hl{something}`. I think this would be the same process.

I have a filter that looks like this:

```
return {
  {
    Str = function (elem)
      if elem.text == "hello" then
        return pandoc.Emph {pandoc.Str "hello"}
      else
        return elem
      end
    end,
  }
}
```

this works, it replaces any instance of "hello" with an italicized version of the word. HOWEVER, it only works with whole words. e.g. if "hello" were part of a word, it wouldn't touch it. Since the equal signs are read as part of one word, it won't touch those.

How do I modify this (or, please, suggest another filter) so that it CAN replace and change parts of a word?

Thank you!

this works, it replaces any instance of "hello" with an italicized version of the word. HOWEVER, it only works with whole words. e.g. if "hello" were part of a word, it wouldn't touch it. Since the equal signs are read as part of one word, it won't touch those.

How do I modify this (or, please, suggest another filter) so that it CAN replace and change parts of a word?

Thank you!

Comment: Side note: I honestly admire your determination to get answers to your question with posts to at least two other platforms. Probably not necessary, but still commendable!

Comment: Thanks, haha, I'm really struggling with this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string like `Hello, World!` becomes a list of inlines in pandoc: `[ Str "Hello,", Space, Str "World!" ]`. Lua filters don't make matching on that particularly convenient: the best method is currently to write a filter for `Inlines` and then iterate over the list to find matching items.

For a complete example, see https://gist.github.com/tarleb/a0646da1834318d4f71a780edaf9f870.

Assuming we already found the highlighted text and converted it to a Span with with class `mark`. Then we can convert that to LaTeX with

```lua
function Span (span)
  if span.classes:includes 'mark' then
    return {pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\hl{')} ..
      span.content ..
      {pandoc.RawInline('latex', '}')}
  end
end
```

Note that the current development version of pandoc, which will become pandoc 3 at some point, supports highlighted text out of the box when called with

```
pandoc --from=markdown+mark ...
```

E.g.,

```
echo '==Hi Mom!==' | pandoc -f markdown+mark -t latex
⇒ \hl{Hi Mom!}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure I understand though. Are you saying that `function Span` is something I can use or something that needs definition of class `mark`?

Because so far this isn't working, I think. Thanks!

Comment: The above assumes that the second filter is run in addition to and after the linked example; i.e., write a second file and pass `--lua-filter` a second time on the command line. But you could also modify the `Span` function in that example so it becomes `local function markup_inlines (inlines)
  return {pandoc.RawInline('tex', '\\hl{')} .. inlines .. {pandoc.RawInline('tex', '}')}
end`. But the second filter approach is a little cleaner.

Comment: All right, so I have a `highlight.lua` and your `Span.lua` with the `mark`. 

However, now I'm getting an error:

`highlight.lua:38:attempt to call a nil value (field 'Inlines') stack traceback`

Comment: OMG; I followed your advice on that git page, and saw that I was still using pandoc 2.9.x because my Linux distro (Mint)'s repo is behind a bit I guess. So I installed the newest .deb and now it WORKS. Thank you so much!!

Comment: This is still working, but I have a question, that I posted on that linked gist page.

Comment: how would I go about putting both those things into one file? If I just add `local`... to the end of the highlight.lua it doesn't work.