# .md to .pdf via Latex: Using a lua-filter to convert custom highlighting that's technically **==bold-highlight==**

Tags: lua, latex, pandoc

Using the solution in my other thread as a jumping off point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74700448/17505879

I'd like to find out if there's a way to convert custom CSS Obsidian highlighting that's `**==blue==**` into LaTex highlighting that looks like `\hlblue{blue}`.

I tried using this filter: https://gist.github.com/tarleb/a0646da1834318d4f71a780edaf9f870

but all it does it turn the highlighted text bold and highlighted, I'd like it to turn blue.

Is this possible? That likely means that `**== ==**` would need to be parsed as a entirely new code (what's that called?) and not as a combination of bold and highlighting.

If it's possible, how would I achieve this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Every Lua string has string methods.
Therefore you can do conversion/translation direct with gsub().
Example done in Lua standalone

```
€ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> css=[[h1{color:**==red==**;}
>> h2{color:**==green==**;}
>> h3{color:**==blue==**;}]]
> -- Lets use gsub() directly on string css
> css:gsub('%*+%=+%l+%=+%*+', {['**==red==**'] = '\\hlred{red}'})
h1{color:\hlred{red};}
h2{color:**==green==**;}
h3{color:**==blue==**;}     1
> -- translation table is growing? So source it out in a table...
> tr_table = {['**==red==**'] = '\\hlred{red}', ['**==green==**'] = '\\hlgreen{green}', ['**==blue==**'] = '\\hlblue{blue}'}
> -- Using tr_table in gsub() now
> css:gsub('%*+%=+%l+%=+%*+', tr_table)
h1{color:\hlred{red};}
h2{color:\hlgreen{green};}
h3{color:\hlblue{blue};}    3
> -- What will be converted/translated/exchanged depends on pattern match
> css:gsub('%*+%=+blue%=+%*+', tr_table)
h1{color:**==red==**;}
h2{color:**==green==**;}
h3{color:\hlblue{blue};}    1
```